# Cannot fin 'InstanceID' and 'InstanceIDTokenHandler' on swift project after updated Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm with an old project that needed to update Firebase, so I did.
After that, I get two errors and I can't understand how to solve them. Could anyone help me with this, please?

File1.swift:

```
func token(withAuthorizedEntity authorizedEntity: String, scope: String, options: [AnyHashable: Any]? = nil, handler: @escaping InstanceIDTokenHandler) {
    
}
```

error: Cannot find type 'InstanceIDTokenHandler' in scope

File2.swift

```
func checkDeviceToken() {
    let hasDeviceToken: Bool      =  self.devicesTokenUseCase.hasDeviceToken()
    let dontHaveDeviceToken: Bool = !hasDeviceToken

    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, _) in
        if let result = result {
            let isNotSameToken: Bool = !self.devicesTokenUseCase.isSameDeviceToken(deviceToken: result.token)

            if hasDeviceToken && isNotSameToken {
                self.updateDeviceToken(token: result.token)
            } else if dontHaveDeviceToken {
                self.sendDeviceToken(token: result.token)
            }
        } else {
            self.checkDeviceToken()
        }
    }
}
```

error: Cannot find 'InstanceID' in scope

Answer (score 6):

Instance IDs have been deprecated, and removed in recent SDK release.

The new tokens that FCM uses to target messages are called Installation IDs. You can [get the current token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#fetching-the-current-registration-token) for your app instance by calling `Messaging.messaging().token`.

After you get the token, you can treat it the same as before.